# Soft Body Object on an Animated Object

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, physics, soft-body

I am new to Blender and wanted to do a project with soft-body physics. I settled on a Jello factory but have been having issues moving the Jello around.

[image]

I want it to be carried on a plate similar to what is shown above. The issue arises when I animate the plate. The plate moves too fast and the Jello slides off.

[image]

The Jello is already the child of the plate but that doesn't do anything in simulations. I have already tried force fields, friction value, and mass but it keeps sliding off. I could animate the plate slower but then I would have to undo all the other 300+ frames of other objects' keyframes since they are all dependent on the timing of the plate. Is there any way I can anchor the vertices of the Jello to the plate? Or increase a value other than friction to make it harder to slide around?

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I haven't updated to 3.1 yet. I plan to do so after this project so I am still running Blender 3.0.

Comment: I can see you want to play with soft body physics but in this case that would complicate matters unnecessarily.  A simple hook would do the job without the hassle you've encountered. See video link in the next comment.

You can have the jellow moving at whatever pace you like and remain 'glued' to the plate.  Jellow characteristics are emulated with the keyframed hook.  You might also like to look at Cage rigging, Lattice modifier, and even the Laplacian deform modifier as (more complex) alternatives.

Continued...

Comment: Cont...  At the link below are two video clips demonstrating the effect you can get get using a single hook.  I see you're new to Blender so if you want more info and the Blend file, just leave a note here and I'll write it up as to how it was done.

The clips -

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_PhAq6L1RLkszyoZcg?e=Wy9rgT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a vertex group to your jelly that will pin it to the plate. Select the bottom of your jelly, assign it to a group, in the settings of the jelly activate *Goal* and choose the vertex group, when you'll move the jelly, its bottom will stay still:

[image]

My settings, under *Goal* make sure that you've put the *Default* at 1 so that the vertex group doesn't move:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for. How do you pin it to the plate as you said? I animated the Jello the same as the plate and it looks fine until I add the soft body physics. I was able to recreate the gif that you have above in another blend file but in the bigger project it still slides off and then kinda sticks to the bottom even with the new vertex group settings. Any ideas?

Comment: my Goal > Strengths settings are: Default > 1, Min > 0.3, Max > 1, I'll edit my answer to put all my settings